# "remote file operation failed" on Hudson

Tags: windows, hudson

I am running a Windows slave for Husdon 1.337 (Linux master). When running a project on the Windows node, it fails with the following message:

```
Building remotely on winTestSlave
Checking out a fresh workspace because there's no workspace at C:\hudson\***\ejb
remote file operation failed
```

It did work yesterday and I have not upgraded Hudson or changed its configurations (or the slave's configurations) in any way. I establish the connection between the slave and the master by running the following command on a cygwim prompt on the slave:

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://myserver/computer/winTestSlave/slave-agent.jnlp
```

I saw the issue http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-5374 and did as instructed in the work-around but that did not work. I also tried with a newer version of slave.jar (version 1.356) but that did not work either. The user connecting to the master is the same user who owns the concerned files/catalogs and has full access rights to them.

Does anyone please have any idea of how to fix this? I really cannot find more information anywhere else!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you start your Windows slave. For my part windows host and windows or unix slaves I had no problem. The Windows slave was installed as a service and the unix slaves are controlled via ssh. Never had a problem with creation of the directories. Try checking the permissions for the directories. I had heard interesting stories of what could happen when the user that the master runs on was changed.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows slaves, I would highly recommend using the slave as a Windows Service. It makes it easier, and you can control whether to start the slave manually or automatically through services.msc.

http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Installing+Hudson+as+a+Windows+service